# how to use shake to page navigate

Tags: android

I want to develop a application which navigates through pages using the phone shake. My  app's main page has 2 buttons. I used this basic code, but I cannot understand how page navigation is done. Please give me a solution.

```
public class mainactivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.shake);
        findViewById(R.id.pw).startAnimation(shake);
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent my = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), path.class);
        startActivityForResult(my, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague. Are you getting any errors? I see you are using a shake Animation on what I guess is the password TextView, but I don't see any Accelerometer analysis. Anyway your code should work, assuming that you have a class called `path`. Naming convention suggests that classes should start with a capital letter (like Activity, Animation, Button) so I renamed your class to `Path`. It should look like this:

```
public class Path extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.path);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Now in your Manifest.xml file you need this:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".mainactivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Path" /> <!-- Add me! -->
</application>
```

Lastly I'm going to make the assumption that `loginButton` is a Button, not generic View. In this case, your `loginButton` code should look like this:

```
Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
loginButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Hope that helps, good luck!

**Addition**

Here is a sample of how to implement recognize a generic shake movement:

```
public class Example extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
      private float mAccCurrent;
      private float mAccLast;
      private SensorManager mSensorManager;
      private int mShakeCount = 0;
      private TextView mText;

      // Sensor events
      public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
          mAccLast = mAccCurrent;
          mAccCurrent = (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(event.values[0], 2) + Math.pow(event.values[1], 2) + Math.pow(event.values[2], 2)));
          float acceleration = mAccCurrent - mAccLast;
          mText.setText(acceleration + "");
          if(Math.abs(acceleration) > 2) {
              Toast.makeText(this, "Shake " + mShakeCount++, 1).show();
              // Navigate here
          }
      }

      public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {}

      // Activity events
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.main);
          mText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

          mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
          mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
          mAccCurrent = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
          super.onResume();
          mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
      }

      @Override
      protected void onStop() {
          mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
          super.onStop();
      }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: yes this is work in for button click.i need to give 1 shake for navigate to the another page.so that's why i used shake.if user shake 1 then page should be navigate according to the shake..

Comment: What have your tried? If you want an example of how to use the Accelerometer see the [Accelerometer Play](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/src/com/example/android/accelerometerplay/AccelerometerPlayActivity.html) included in the Android SDK.

Comment: ShakeEvent mSensorListener; get errors. so i cannot do it perfectly        http://pastebin.com/TvUVv0Eh

Comment: What is a ShakeEvent? This is not a built-in Android class. Wherever you copied this code from has a class called ShakeEvent you need to copy this file too. Alternatively, here is a second example that works: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/a-quick-tutorial-on-coding-androids-accelerometer/472

Comment: yes i cannot understand about the ShakeEvent.i just copy that code.how i create shakeevent.i mean as a class or interface.please guide me

Comment: i tried your code.but how i apply it into my code.if you can please give me sample code.i need to navigate page using the shake opetion

Answer (score 0):

public class ACTIVITY extends Activity  {

```
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            SensorManager mSensorManager;

            ShakeEvent mSensorListener;

            mSensorListener = new ShakeEvent();
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);


            mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEvent.OnShakeListener() {

              public void onShake() {
                  Intent i = new Intent(Shake.this, NEWACTIVITY.class);
                  startActivity(i);
              }
            });
        }}
```

Comment: but it getting errors when used the  ShakeEvent mSensorListener;but this will help to basic step to do the page navigate.if any one have another idea please post it.